# Render of animation all black

Tags: rendering, animation

I have looked at literally almost every post about this issue but none of them fixed my problem. If you can help me I would not be able to thank you enough! you can download it here [image]

Comment: If that link is you .blend file, please consider uploading it to [Blend-Exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) instead. As it is now, the file is marked private on Google Drive, and can't be accesssed by anyone whom you haven't explicitly granted permission.

Comment: ok I have fixed the link now!

Comment: "I have looked at literally almost every post about this issue" - I think not. How many were there?

Comment: @JanDvorak there's over a hundred of them... http://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=blank+render

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/81225/blank-final-rendering

Answer (score 3):

You've got both an animation in the 3D Viewport set up, as well as a Sequence in the Video Sequence Editor within the same scene. The sequence in the VSE now seems to take precedence over the 3D Viewport Rendering. So essentially, when you do a render, instead of using Blender Render to knock out the frames of your animation, the VSE is trying to read the PNGs defined in the sequence strip, and spits out those.

To "fix" this, you can disable the Sequencer output in the `Post Processing` tab under the Render Settings. Disable the checkbox called `Sequencer` and render your animation.

[image: Post Processing Tab]

Once done, you can enable the `Sequencer` checkbox again when you're ready to cut the video strips.

Personal Recommendation: To avoid this kind of confusion, create a second scene in your Blend File to separate animation from video editing. This way, Rendering and Animation can have their needed settings, while Video Editing can have completely different ones.